# javascript remove (empty) array from assoc array

Tags: javascript, associative-array

I have an assoc js array and i want to remove one element from it.
My solution works but it is not really nice, is there a better solution?

```
// i got this assoc array
var cm = [];
    cm["a"] = ["a"];
    cm["b"] = ["c"];
    cm["s"] = ["a", "b", "c"];
    cm["x"] = [];
console.log(cm);

var searchKey = "s";
var p = ["a","c","d", "b"]; // to remove from searchKey array

// remove elements (works fine)
cm[searchKey] = cm[searchKey].filter(value => (p.includes(value) === false));
console.log(cm); // now cm[searchKey] is an empty array

// if the array at index 'searchKey' is empty remove it from assoc array
var newarray = [];
if (cm[searchKey].length===0)
{
    for(key in cm)
  {
    if (key!=searchKey) newarray[key] = cm[key];
  }
}
cm = newarray;
console.log(cm);
```

I tried with filter and splice, but both works only at arrays not assoc array.

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have associative arrays. You're misusing the JS Array type.

Comment: `cm` is not an associative array. You shouldn't be doing that - you are actually making an *array* but then just treating it as an *object* by setting properties on it. You should be instantiating an object instead by using `cm = {}`

Comment: Seems that you want your code reviewed and improved, but you haven't given qualifications for what counts as "nice" or "better" code.

Comment: You're right, but the upper part (the 'assoc' array) is given (dont ask why) the hole array is handled like an object. delete works!

Comment: @Sebastian yes, `delete` would work. Just because you *can* do something doesn't mean you *should*.

Comment: why should i not use delte? on normal array it leaves the undefiend stuff, but not in this case. the empty array with key is complete removed.

Comment: It works until `var searchKey = "length";`

Comment: @Sebastian you shouldn't be using *an array*.

Comment: ok I understand. But like i said, the assoc array isn't created by me, its the 'framework' i use, maybe i try to change this in the framework later. And the searchKey will never be "length", I controll the searchKey and its ahas very few options.

Answer (score 2):

You have an object, so you can just do:

```
if (cm[searchKey].length===0)
{
    delete cm[searchKey]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You might need Map. I think Map does a better job that you actually ask for.

Answer (score 1):

This is a perfect usecase for a Map:

```
  class Multimap extends Map {
    get(key) {
      return super.get(key) || [];
    }

    addTo(key, value) {
      if(this.has(key)) {
         this.get(key).push(value);
       } else {
         this.set(key, [value]);
       }
    }

    removeFrom(key, value) {
      this.set(key, this.get(key).filter(el => el !== value));
    }
}
```

This can be used as:

```
 const cm = new Multimap([
  ["a", ["a", "b", "c"]]
 ]);

 cm.removeFrom("a", "b");
 cm.get("a").includes("b") // false
```

Answer (score 0):

I used `.filter` on the array like so

```
// Remove emptys
modeSummary = modeSummary.filter(ms => ms);
```